# Auth Guard is calling auth service constructor every time it is being checked

Tags: angular

I have auth service which creates a user$ observable if there is a user then it will fetch the document from firestore if not will return null, and there are other login and create user methods.

This auth service is being injected into two guard AuthGuard & LoggedInAuthGuard & various components

But i observed that whenever there is a change in route then the auth guard will be invoked the auth service constructor is being called everytime

i tried removing AppRoutingModule by moving the code into the AppModule but still the Guard are calling the service constructor everytime they are invoked

AuthService

```
imports...
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthService {

  user$: Observable<User>;
  private authError = new BehaviorSubject<string>('');
  authError$ = this.authError.asObservable();
  doc: AngularFirestoreDocument<User>;

  constructor(
    private afAuth: AngularFireAuth,
    private afs: AngularFirestore,
    private router: Router
  ) {
    // Get the auth state, then fetch the Firestore user document or 
return null
    this.user$ = this.afAuth.authState.pipe(
      switchMap(user => {
        // Logged in
        if (user) {
          // Test when multiple request are being sent
          console.log(user.toJSON(), new Date().getMilliseconds());           this.doc = this.afs.doc<User>(`users/${user.uid}`);
          return this.doc.valueChanges();
        } else {
          // Logged out
          return of(null);
        }
      })
    );
  }

// other Login & create user methos
```

AuthGuard

```
imports...

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
    return this.auth.user$.pipe(
      take(1),
      map(user => !!user), // <-- map to boolean
      tap(loggedIn => {
        if (!loggedIn) {
          this.router.navigate(['/login']);
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

LoggedInAuthGuard

```
imports
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LoggedInAuthGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(
    private auth: AuthService,
    private router: Router
  ) { }
  canActivate(
    next: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean> {
      return this.auth.user$.pipe(
        take(1),
        map(user => !!user),
        tap(loggedIn => {
          if(loggedIn) {
            this.router.navigate(['/account']);
          }
        })
      );
  }
}
```

AppModule

```
imports ....

@NgModule({
  decalaration:[...],
  imports: [...,
    AppRoutingModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

AppRoutingModule

```
imports ...

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    redirectTo: '/dashboard',
    pathMatch: 'full'
  },
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    canActivate: [LoggedInAuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'register',
    component: RegisterComponent,
    canActivate: [LoggedInAuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    component: DashboardComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'mylist',
    component: MyListComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'explore',
    component: ExploreComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'contribute',
    component: ContributeComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'account',
    component: AccountComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuard]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

In Console where i log the data from the firestore i expected to be it running only once but everytime i change i get error

GitHub - https://github.com/patel-malav/Project-Birdie/tree/website-2.0

Image of Console - https://github.com/patel-malav/Project-Birdie/blob/website-2.0/website-revamp/Screenshot%20from%202019-09-15%2014-56-55.png

Comment: Have you tried to define the service in app module providers array?

Comment: @galvan yes i have tried that already but still the same result that constructor is firing multiple times